# How to include separate config file in NodeRED

Tags: configuration, settings, freebsd, node-red, jail

How would I include a a separate `settings.js` file for my Node-RED configuration?

I am running node-red within a freebsd jail, and like to host all my config files in a mounted location for snapshot/backup/samba purposes.

Ideally, I'm hoping to have the main `settings.js` file include a single line, similar to `include /usr/home/nodered/mnt/config/settings.js` - and have all of the main settings contained within the custom included file.

The `include` argument works as expected for applications such as nginx/mosquitto/etc, however I'm not able to find the correct syntax for node-red

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong, don't link the `settings.js` to some other file, put the whole `userDir` on the mounted volume (this is the way the official Node-RED docker containers work...)

This way you back up the `settings.js`, `flow.json`, `creds_flow.json` and `.config.json` files as well as any extra nodes installed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already got those files referenced to a custom location (flows, TLS certs, etc).
 My reason for not changing the ```userDir``` is that it saves a whole bunch of other files that I don't want to be backed up.  My concern being that if I need to reinstall node-red in a rebuilt jail there will be possible versioning issues from old nodes.  However referencing the specific files I want individually will avoid this, as they are effectively just a few configs, certs and my main flow.  So unfortunately it doesn't answer the question...

Comment: You want those files backed up to ensure you get the same versions later. But in that case just use the `--settings` option on the Node-RED command line to specify where to find it.